# Google Apps Script sidebar not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

I'm trying to setup a sidebar for my Google Apps Script project. I am admittedly not the best with html so I found an open source accordion menu that has the look and functionality I am looking for. However, I cannot get it to load properly as a sidebar for Google Apps Script. I split the HTML, CSS, and Javascript into three separate HTML files and then loaded them into the primary HTML as suggested by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#code.gs) (yes I have created the include() function in my script as you can see. My Google Apps Script file and three HTML files are shown below. It loads, but it appears to be devoid of any CSS.

I tried adding a script line to my Javascript file to load jQuery, although not sure if it was done correctly. Much appreciation for any help.

Google Apps Script File:

```
function buildSidebar() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('SidebarHTML').evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();    
}

function showSidebar() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(buildSidebar());
}
```

Primary HTML File (named SidebarHTML.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('SidebarCSS'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <aside class="sidebar">
      <div id="leftside-navigation" class="nano">
        <ul class="nano-content">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i><span>UI Elements</span><i class="arrow fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
            <ul>

              <li><a href="ui-alerts-notifications.html">Alerts &amp; Notifications</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="ui-panels.html">Panels</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="ui-buttons.html">Buttons</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="ui-slider-progress.html">Sliders &amp; Progress</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="ui-modals-popups.html">Modals &amp; Popups</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="ui-icons.html">Icons</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="ui-grid.html">Grid</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="ui-tabs-accordions.html">Tabs &amp; Accordions</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="ui-nestable-list.html">Nestable Lists</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-table"></i><span>Tables</span><i class="arrow fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="tables-basic.html">Basic Tables</a>
              </li>

              <li><a href="tables-data.html">Data Tables</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa fa-tasks"></i><span>Forms</span><i class="arrow fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="forms-components.html">Components</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="forms-validation.html">Validation</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="forms-mask.html">Mask</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="forms-wizard.html">Wizard</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="forms-multiple-file.html">Multiple File Upload</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="forms-wysiwyg.html">WYSIWYG Editor</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="sub-menu active">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span>Mail</span><i class="arrow fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
            <ul>
              <li class="active"><a href="mail-inbox.html">Inbox</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="mail-compose.html">Compose Mail</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i><span>Charts</span><i class="arrow fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="charts-chartjs.html">Chartjs</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="charts-morris.html">Morris</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="charts-c3.html">C3 Charts</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span>Maps</span><i class="arrow fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="map-google.html">Google Map</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="map-vector.html">Vector Map</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="typography.html"><i class="fa fa-text-height"></i><span>Typography</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-file"></i><span>Pages</span><i class="arrow fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="pages-blank.html">Blank Page</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="pages-login.html">Login</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="pages-sign-up.html">Sign Up</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="pages-calendar.html">Calendar</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="pages-timeline.html">Timeline</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="pages-404.html">404</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="pages-500.html">500</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <?!= include('SidebarJava'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS HTML File (named SidebarCSS.html)

```
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700');
  @import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css');
  body {
    color: #5D5F63;
    background: #293949;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  }
  .sidebar-toggle {
    margin-left: -240px;
  }
  .sidebar {
    width: 240px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #293949;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
    #leftside-navigation {
      ul, ul ul {
        margin: -2px 0 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      ul {
        li {
          list-style-type: none;
          border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.05);
          &.active {
            & > a {
              color: #1abc9c;
            }
            ul {
              display: block;
            }
          }
          a {
            color: #aeb2b7;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            padding: 18px 0 18px 25px;
            font-size: 12px;
            outline: 0;
            -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
            -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
            -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
            -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
            transition: all 200ms ease-in;
            &:hover {
              color: #1abc9c;
            }
            span {
              display: inline-block;
            }
            i {
              width: 20px;
              .fa-angle-left, .fa-angle-right {
                padding-top: 3px;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      ul ul {
        display: none;
        li {
          background: #23313f;
          margin-bottom: 0;
          margin-left: 0;
          margin-right: 0;
          border-bottom: none;
          a {
            font-size: 12px;
            padding-top: 13px;
            padding-bottom: 13px;
            color: #aeb2b7;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
</style>
```

Javascript HTML file (named SidebarJava.html)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

  $("#leftside-navigation .sub-menu > a").click(function(e) {
    $("#leftside-navigation ul ul").slideUp(), $(this).next().is(":visible") || $(this).next().slideDown(),
    e.stopPropagation()
  })

</script>
```

Comment: How do you call `showSidebar()` ? Have you added a custom menu or something?

Comment: I ran your code, and it seemed to work correctly. In Chrome's Developer Console, jquery and your CSS files seemed to be downloaded. And the sidebar's background color is correctly painted with your CSS's background-color value. I posted an [image](https://imgur.com/a/prhs6lA) about this. pls, check it.

Comment: Yes I have showSidebar() attached to a custom menu that I run it from.

Comment: That image is how it looks when I load it right now. It is supposed to look like this: https://codepen.io/maggiben/pen/rCIFu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SidebarCSS.html, there are nested blocks. These are not allowed in normal CSS files ( Unless using SCSS or something).
So you should flatten these CSS blocks as you intend.

As I mentioned in the above comment, it seems to work fine for downloading JS files and CSS files.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thanks.

Comment: I found the un-nested css code on the original code's site listed as the compiled version of the css. Works now. Thanks!